# Drawable Panel above toolbars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity containing - `Toolbar`, `Tabs`, `ViewPager`, `FloatingActionButton` and `DraggablePanel`.

When my initialize my draggable panel, it appears below the `Toolbar`, `FloatingButton` and `Tabs`. Setting `DraggablePanel.bringToFront()` brings it only above `ViewPager`. How do I bring my `DraggablePanel` above everything when initialized?

> Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:draggable_panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="in.brewtv.activities.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/change_mood" />

    <!-- DraggablePanel -->

    <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel
        android:id="@+id/draggable_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        draggable_panel:x_scale_factor="2.3"
        draggable_panel:y_scale_factor="2.3"
        draggable_panel:top_fragment_height="200dp"
        draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_right="10dp"
        draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_bottom="10dp"
        draggable_panel:enable_horizontal_alpha_effect="true"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Screen shots:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @azizbekian - Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set an **elevation**, higher value than your **FAB** to your **DraggablePanel**

```
 <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel
    android:id="@+id/draggable_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    draggable_panel:x_scale_factor="2.3"
    draggable_panel:y_scale_factor="2.3"
    draggable_panel:top_fragment_height="200dp"
    draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_right="10dp"
    draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_bottom="10dp"
    draggable_panel:enable_horizontal_alpha_effect="true"/>
```